# Text editor with tile view

Tags: windows, text-editor

I am looking for a Windows text editor that allows me to tile 3-4 files inside one window.

Basically like this ["Tile Tabs" Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tile-tabs/).

Currently I am using Notepad++ with multiple instances to achieve this. In one instance of Notepad++, only 2 Tiles are supported.

Comment: Which operating system? Free, or willing to pay? And other desirable features, or just tiling? The more you tell us, them more we can help you

Answer (score 4):

## [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

Emacs is a cross-platform and very customizable open-source text editor. It allows you to tile and resize multiple windows and frames using simple keyboard shortcuts.

[Here is the manual page on that feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows.html#Windows)

> Emacs can split a frame into two or many windows. Multiple windows can display parts of different buffers, or different parts of one buffer.

[Here you can download it for Windows](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/)

Example (click image for larger version):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't specify "gratis" - [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit/features.html) costs [a hefty $80](http://www.ultraedit.com/catalog.html), but it is a long established & extremely powerful editor. I used it for years until I found the price too steep, but YMMV.

> List of open files (close/save/tile/print selected files
>   Tile edit windows horizontally/vertically

Why not try [the demo version](http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/ultraedit_download.html) and see what you think?

> You can split the window as many times as you want and drag as many
>   tabs as you need to any of the split windows, providing you even more
>   edit window management authority.
>   [image]

Comment: Gosh I dont think it cost me that much when I purchased it a few years back, but it is a powerful editor that I still use on a daily basis.

Comment: I remember buying the first few versions, when it cost $29, but that was decade ago (maybe two). It is a very powerful tool, but with many freeware alternatives, I couldn't justify $80 now :-(

Answer (score 2):

For a free solution, you an consider Eclipse. It is primarily used for software development, but [it can do what your want](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fplatform_tips.html):

> You can use drag and drop to modify the layout of your editor work
>   area. Grab an editor or view tab and drag it to the edge of the editor
>   work area.
>   [image]

Answer (score 2):

**SynWrite** editor; free.

Menu under `rectangle` button; open 1/2/3/4 or 6 panes at one editor.

[image: N views]

Answer (score 2):

You want to see **multiple** files in **single** Notepad, the use the **“NOTEPADTABS”** which allows you to make a group of text files to work on large projects. NotepadTabs is a **free** software ***text editor*** that let you to view file in different tabs style like horizontal, vertical, etc. Download this text editor for free from here

http://www.notepadtabs.com/

Comment: I like the simplicity of the suggested programm. The tabs look nice, but it isn't really a webeditor.

Answer (score 2):

Another text editor that supports tile view is **[Github Atom](https://atom.io)**. Atom is hackable text editor for the 21st century. Github Atom is free, available for [Windows](https://atom.io/download/windows) operating system. You can **tile your view** (**splitting your pane is the synonym** for Github Atom editor *context*). As mentioned in the latest version of Github Atom [documentation](https://atom.io/docs/v0.179.0/getting-started).

> **Split Panes**
>
> You can **split** any editor pane **horizontally** or **vertically** by using `cmd-k right` or `cmd-k down`. Once you have a split
>   pane, you can move focus between them with `cmd-k` `cmd-right` or `cmd-k`
>   `cmd-down`. To close a pane, close all its editors with `cmd-w`, then
>   press `cmd-w` one more time to close the pane. You can configure panes
>   to auto-close when empty in the Settings view.

I have tried this one. For simple execution, when you are on Github Atom editor, press `Ctrl + Shift + P`. Then, type "`split`", you will see **four options** of splitting panes which you can choose. The result is right below:

[image: splitting your Github Atom panes]

Comment: sure @Type-Style.
You're welcome ((:

Answer (score 1):

[Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) would let you do that - I'm using the keyboard shortcuts to do this but it lets you do 1,2,3 or 4 columns, and tabs within those columns/

[image]

Free to try (and its *polite* nagware, with a UNREGISTERED in the text editor title and no toher limits), and 70 dollars if you want an single user licence you can use anywhere.